# How to extract specific value from this json string using linq

Tags: c#, json, linq

could anyone help me extract the specific value for [downloads][csv][href] out of the following json string please?

```
{
"@context": "https://cdn.ons.gov.uk/assets/json-ld/context.json",
"alerts": [],
"collection_id": "cmdr",
"dimensions": [
    various dimensions here
],
"downloads": {
    "csv": {
        "href": "https://download.beta.ons.gov.uk/downloads/datasets/regional-gdp-by-year/editions/time-series/versions/4.csv",
        "size": "568021"
    },
    "csvw": {
        "href": "ref",
        "size": "1903"
    },
    "xls": {
        "href": "ref",
        "size": "80768"
    }
},
"edition": "time-series",
"id": "5c",
"links": {
    "dataset": {
        "href": "ref",
        "id": "regional-gdp-by-year"
    },
    "edition": {
        "href": "ref",
        "id": "time-series"
    },
    "self": {
        "href": "ref"
    }
},
"release_date": "2021",
"state": "published",
"usage_notes": [],
"version": 4
```

}

the current code I am using returns nothing:

```
        var labels = JObject.Parse(observationsJson)["downloads"];
        var results = labels.Select(data => new
        {
            label = (string)data["href"]
        });
        foreach (var item in results)
        {
            csvDownloadAddress = item.label;
        }
```

If there is another method rather than using linq then I am open to suggestions.
Sorry if this is a dumb quest, my experience with linq and json is very limited.
thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `JSON Path`, that can be used to select `specific` element(s) from the JSON string.
see Newtonsoft [example](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/queryjsonselecttoken.htm), or you can use this [JsonPath](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JsonPath.Net/0.1.3) Nuget package.

The JsonPath Nuget can be used like below,

```
    var input = "$.downloads.csv.href";
    var path = JsonPath.Parse(input);
    var hrefVal = path.Evaluate(jsonStr);
```